# String Content Compare

Tags: c#, regex, vb.net, string

I need to compare the content of two strings and if "keywords" are occurring in both strings.
Here are two examples (Equal parts are highlighted in bold):

FUTURE **EURO** BUND 03.16 **CALL** 03.16 BP **159,50** EUREX

ETD **CALL** MAR 16 ERX **EURO** BUND**159.50**

Keywords are words like PUT and CALL, Numbers can be comma or dot delimited.
The date 03.16 would be great to compare to MAR 16, but the occurrence of the keywords is not known. There is also something like a rule, if certain Keywords exist in one string like "CALL", then "PUT" is not allowed in the second string.

Another Example with different Date styles:

EQOI BUY **PUT** **2.5** ACI US **15/01/16** 000043XI

**PUT** Arch Coal Inc. **15.01.16** BP **2,50** OTC

I was thinking about splitting the strings by a Space and comparing the content one by one, but then I would miss the number in BUND**159.50**, I would need to check the splitted string if it contains a number/numbers dates etc.. Are there any existing libraries I could use for this type of comparison?

Preferable VB.NET, Linq but C# or Regex are also ok.

Which way would you go? I need to compare hundreds of strings and need to make a proposal list which of the strings in the first List would fit best to the strings of the second list.

Comment: Wow, how should we know 03.16 is date or number?

Comment: As I said it would be great, but this part would not be so important. the other Keywords would be more important.

Comment: Clearly you need to identify all possible formats (taking in account parts your are not interested by too, the most precise, the best), and to build your pattern as an alternation of these different formats. Once this job is done, you can try to factorize your pattern for faster results. Otherwise, there is no way to distinguish a date from an amount.

Answer (score 2):

Just for fun

```
^(?=.*?((?:CALL)|(?:PUT))).*?(?<day_type1>\d+.\d+.?\d+).*?(?<num_type1>\d+,\d+)|^(?=.*?((?:CALL)|(?:PUT))).*?(?<day_type2>\w{3}\s\d{2}).*?(?<num_type2>\d+.\d+)|^(?=.*?((?:CALL)|(?:PUT))).*?(?<num_type3>\d+.\d+).*?(?<day_type3>\d+\/\d+\/\d+)
```

[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/dO9mL1/3)

Output:

```
MATCH 1
1.  [23-27] `CALL`
day_type1   [17-22] `03.16`
num_type1   [37-43] `159,50`
MATCH 2
4.  [55-59] `CALL`
day_type2   [60-66] `MAR 16`
num_type2   [80-86] `159.50`
MATCH 3
7.  [97-100]    `PUT`
num_type3   [101-104]   `2.5`
day_type3   [112-120]   `15/01/16`
MATCH 4
1.  [131-134]   `PUT`
day_type1   [150-158]   `15.01.16`
num_type1   [162-166]   `2,50`
```

Added more date format:

```
^(?=.*?((?:CALL)|(?:PUT)))(?=.*?\s(?<day>(?<day_type1>\d+[.\/]\d+[.\/]?\d+)|(?<day_type2>\w{3}\s\d{2})|(?<day_type3>\d+\/\d+\/\d+)|(?<day_type4>\d+\s\w{3}\s\d{2})))(?=.*\s[a-zA-Z]*(?<num>(?<num_type1>\d+,\d+)|(?<num_type2>\d+\.\d+)|(?:(?<num_type3>\d+\.\d+))))
```

[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/oQ4yY3/1)

Output:

```
MATCH 1
1.  [23-27] `CALL`
day [17-22] `03.16`
day_type1   [17-22] `03.16`
num [37-43] `159,50`
num_type1   [37-43] `159,50`
MATCH 2
1.  [55-59] `CALL`
day [60-66] `MAR 16`
day_type2   [60-66] `MAR 16`
num [80-86] `159.50`
num_type2   [80-86] `159.50`
MATCH 3
1.  [97-100]    `PUT`
day [112-120]   `15/01/16`
day_type1   [112-120]   `15/01/16`
num [101-104]   `2.5`
num_type2   [101-104]   `2.5`
MATCH 4
1.  [131-134]   `PUT`
day [150-158]   `15.01.16`
day_type1   [150-158]   `15.01.16`
num [162-166]   `2,50`
num_type1   [162-166]   `2,50`
MATCH 5
1.  [172-175]   `PUT`
day [191-199]   `9 OCT 13`
day_type4   [191-199]   `9 OCT 13`
num [203-207]   `2,50`
num_type1   [203-207]   `2,50`
MATCH 6
1.  [213-216]   `PUT`
day [232-241]   `29 FEB 16`
day_type4   [232-241]   `29 FEB 16`
num [245-249]   `2,50`
num_type1   [245-249]   `2,50`
```

Ex: 29 FEB 16

```
|(?<day_type4>\d+\s\w{3}\s\d{2})
```

Explanation:
`|` or
`(?<day_type4>` group name `day_type4`
`\d+\s\w{3}\s\d{2}` day format
`\d` number
`\s` blank
`\w{3}` 3 letters word

Comment: That is some neat regex'in!

Comment: @Tim007 This is a very interesting Regex! How would you extend it if in the one string is a Date like 19 OCT 13 or 29 FEB 16 and in the other string it is reflected as  19.10.13 or 13.02.16. Now I need to find out how to extract all regex matches into a list which I could be compared to the second string.

Comment: @Athu : check update, add like this `|(?<day_type_n>***CODE HERE***)` to extent it.

Answer (score 1):

Your post is overly broad and contains too many questions, thus only the most important (per your definition) would be addressed, namely: finding the keyword "PUT" and "CALL" in 2 strings and applying some logical conditions. Assuming that you have the following sample strings:

```
string str1 ="FUTURE EURO BUND 03.16 CALL 03.16 BP 159,50 EUREX"
string str2 ="ETD CALL MAR 16 ERX EURO BUND159.50"
```

then the check for keyword can be performed by C# String.Contains() method w/logical operations added per you definition (if the first string contains "PUT" then the second one cannot contain "CALL"):

```
if(str1.Contains("PUT") && !str2.Contains("CALL"))
```

Hope this may help.

Answer (score 1):

May be you should try something along these lines? What this will give you, you can now work on the rules how to parse your dates and numbers to unify their representation.

```
dim s1 as string=  "FUTURE EURO BUND 03.16 CALL 03.16 BP 159,50 EUREX"
dim s2 as string = "ETD CALL MAR 16 ERX EURO BUND159.50"

dim whiteList as new List(Of String)(New String() {"CALL", "EURO"})

dim l1 as List(of String) = 
    s1.Split(" ".toCharArray(), StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).
        Where(function(s) whiteList.Contains(s)).ToList()

dim l2 as List(of String) = 
    s2.Split(" ".toCharArray(), stringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).
        Where(function(s) whiteList.Contains(s)).ToList()

dim result = l2.Intersect(l1).ToList()

result.ForEach(sub(s) Console.WriteLine(s))
```

Result:

> CALL
>   EURO